# Issue with using .htaccess file for redirection on apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

For our main company website, we have different 3rd party sources linking back to our website in different formats. Which begin (apologies for not including links as I'm limited to two)

1. http://
2. https://
3. http://www
4. https://www

And I want to redirect any combination back to **https://www.example.com**

Now 4 is obviously already right, 2 works no problem as does 3, but number 4 never works. I can't figure out why though. Below is my .htaccess file, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        # ensure www.
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

        # ensure https
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]      
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, some numpty had edited the virtual host file configuration with a minor typo that I hadn't spotted that was stopping it working for http.